# Lodash - perform calculation on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am struggling with finding the right lodash function, if you could help, that’d be great.

I have an array of:

```json
   [
      { '2002': 2, '2003': 1, '2004': 5 },
      { '2002': 2, '2003': 5, '2004': 2 },
      { '2002': 3, '2003': 2, '2004': 3 },
      { '2002': 5, '2003': 4, '2004': 4 }
    ]
```

As there are 4 different inputs as below:

`[input1, input2, input3, input4]`

For each year I want to perform the following:

`(input1 + input2 - input3) / input4`

In the year 2002, the output: `(2 + 2 - 3) / 5 = 0.2`

Is there a lodash helper function to output:

```
[ [ 2002, 0.2 ], [ 2003, 1 ], [ 2004, 1 ] ]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: With `spread` I can collect all the inputs - but not sure how to pick the year. In this case, spread will allow the following:

`_.spread((input1, input2) => {})([input1, input2, ...])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this very directly with vanilla javascript by mapping over the `Object.keys` of the first object in the array and then using each key to access the relevant properties from each object in the array and perform your calculation on them.

```js
const input = [
  { '2002': 2, '2003': 1, '2004': 5 },
  { '2002': 2, '2003': 5, '2004': 2 },
  { '2002': 3, '2003': 2, '2004': 3 },
  { '2002': 5, '2003': 4, '2004': 4 }
]

const calc = ([a, b, c, d]) => (a + b - c) / d;

const result = Object.keys(input[0]).map(k => [k, calc(input.map(o => o[k]))])

console.log(result)
```

A possible sequence with lodash...

```js
const input = [
  { '2002': 2, '2003': 1, '2004': 5 },
  { '2002': 2, '2003': 5, '2004': 2 },
  { '2002': 3, '2003': 2, '2004': 3 },
  { '2002': 5, '2003': 4, '2004': 4 }
];

const result = _.chain(
  _.mergeWith(...input, (a, b) => [].concat(a, b))
)
  .mapValues(([a, b, c, d]) => (a + b - c) / d)
  .toPairs()
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```